# Detecting cycle in an undirected graph using iterative DFS?

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

So, I implemented the DFS in an iterative manner by the following method:

```
void dfsiter (graph * mygraph, int foo, bool arr[])
{
    stack <int> mystack;
    mystack.push(foo);
    while (mystack.empty() == false)
    {
        int k = mystack.top();
        mystack.pop();
        if (arr[k] == false)
        {
            cout<<k<<"\t";
            arr[k] = true;
            auto it = mygraph->edges[k].begin();
            while (it != mygraph->edges[k].end())
            {
                if (arr[*it] == false)
                {
                    mystack.push(*it);
                }
                it++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The above code works completely fine. Now, I want to detect cycles in an undirected graph using the above code (Iterative DFS). Now, I read that, `If an unexplored edge leads to a node visited before, then the graph contains a cycle.` Therefore, I just want to ask you, how do I exactly keep track of all this?

I have taken my graph to be like this:

```
class graph
{
    public:
    int vertices;
    vector < vector<int> > edges;
};
```

Should I change the above to:

```
class graph
{
    public:
    int vertices;
    vector < vector<pair<int,bool> > edges;
};
```

Where the `bool` for each edge will be marked true? And what changes will I need to do in the above code for DFS for detecting the cycle? I tried but I couldn't really think of a way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to receive as output data?

Comment: I am trying to modify the above iterative DFS for detecting whether there exists a cycle in the undirected graph or not. After doing so, I will try and do it for a directed graph. But I am not really sure, how to modify the above graph to store the required information for finding out such information.

Comment: Isn't the array arr a way to check if a node is already visited? Why you need to modify the graph class to add this information?

Comment: But only by using arr, how will I check for a cycle?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but in this loop:

    if (arr[*it] == false){
        mystack.push(*it);
    }

If you detect that arr[*it] is true, I think you just detected a cycle. In this case, the edge is unexplored because you just visited k for the first time and you found a visited node.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can store a "father" node *f* in DFS tree for each vertex *v*, i.e. the vertex from which DFS came to the vertex *v*. It can be stored in the stack for example. In this case you store pairs in stack, first value is the vertex *v* and the second one is its father *f*.

An undirected graph has a cycle if and only if you meet an edge *vw* going to already visited vertex *w*, which is not the father of *v*.

You can see the modified and cleaned code below.

```
bool hascycle (graph * mygraph, int start, bool visited[])
{
    stack <pair<int, int> > mystack;
    mystack.push(make_pair(start, -1));
    visited[start] = true;

    while (!mystack.empty())
    {
        int v = mystack.top().first;
        int f = mystack.top().second;
        mystack.pop();

        const auto &edges = mygraph->edges[v];
        for (auto it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); it++)
        {
            int w = *it;
            if (!visited[w])
            {
                mystack.push(make_pair(w, v));
                visited[w] = true;
            }
            else if (w != f)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: if the graph is disconnected, then you must start DFS from several vertices, ensuring that the whole graph is visited. It can be done in *O(V + E)* total time.

Comment: Hi, this is perfect. Can you also tell me how can I modify it for a directed graph? Thanks! :)

Comment: You mean, I do, `if (!visited[w]) { ... } else return true?`  Something like this?

Comment: But I don't think so, this will work. Consider the graph with the following edges, `1->2, 1->3, 2->4, 3->4`. Here, their is no cycle, yet it will output there is a cycle since it explores 4 while traversing 3 and then when it comes to 2, 4 is already marked as true.